# Parar o preload somente quando a página carregar por completa

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função em JavaScript que realiza o *preload*, porém o *preload* está em segundos fixos. Gostaria de quando carregar todos os dados da tela, o *preload* ocultasse.

Segue o script atual abaixo:

```
<script>
        $(window).on('load',function(){
            $('.preload-content').fadeOut(2000);
        })
</script>
```

Como posso fazer para realizar o processo da forma correta ?

Comment: Você pode tentar estudar sobre Prefetching, preloading, prebrowsing. https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/

Comment: Você quer que o `.preload-content` desapareça quando a página carregar?

Comment: Extamente G.Otani P.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara, não é só retirar o **fadeOut()**? A página está carregada e ainda fica o preload por um tempo é isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente um desses métodos:

#### Utilizando jQuery `.hide()`

```js
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('.preload-content').hide();
})
```

[fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582629/11138267)

#### Alterando o `style.display` do elemento

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('.preload-content').forEach((elemento) => elemento.style.display = 'none')
}
```

Porém acredito que você deva **usar o `body` no lugar de `window`** no primeiro exemplo.

Comment: Funcionou amigo. muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está correto. Após carregar o objeto `window` será disparado o evento `load` que executará o método `.fadeOut()` no elemento. Só que você está especificando que o fade out irá durar 2 segundos (2000 milissegundos), mas ele será executado logo após o `load`.

Por padrão o fadeOut dura 400 milissegundos se você deixar a duração em branco, mas você pode especificar uma duração mais curta usando "fast", que será de 200 milissegundos:

```
$('.preload-content').fadeOut("fast");
```

Ou então um valor menor ainda para ficar mais rápido:

```
$('.preload-content').fadeOut(100);
```

Ou pode usar o método `.hide()` que esconde o elemento sem efeitos. A direfença entre `.hide()` e `.fadeOut()` é que um esconde o elemento sem nenhum efeito e o outro a mesma coisa, mas com um efeito de esmaecimento antes.

Uma dica também seria remover logo o elemento do DOM, já que ele só serve mesmo na abertura da página. Aí você usa o callback do `.fadeOut()` para isso:

```
$('.preload-content').fadeOut(100, function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Assim o elemento irá esmaecer em 1 décimo de segundo e depois será removido da página em vez de apenas escondido. Veja como fica:

```js
$('.preload-content').fadeOut(100, function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preload-content">Carregando</div>
```